# Is there a testing framework that will support GraphQL, web app testing, and mobile?

Tags: selenium, web-applications, automated-tests, graphql, karate

I have started to use Karate to test our mobile app which is using GraphQL and it is working good so far, though a bit of a learning curve for me as I am not a programmer by trade, but I need to look further into the future and be sure to find a framework that will also support our need to automate tests for our custom web applications as well.  I would think Selenium would be the way to go so I am looking for a testing framework where I can test not only the GraphQL queries which our micro services/APIs are written, but also our web applications and our mobile app.  We are a MS shop but if need be, as with Karate, we can venture into a different stack.  Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: dev of Karate here.

I don't know about mobile, but teams have been successful mixing Karate and Selenium / WebDriver into a single integrated script, which is possible because of Karate's Java inter-op.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233301/143475) is a Stack Overflow answer recommending the above approach and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47795762/143475) is an update from the same team reporting success.

One more reason you may want to consider Karate is that it may be the only framework that allows you to re-use functional test scripts as performance tests, via [Gatling integration](https://twitter.com/ptrthomas/status/986463717465391104) (still in development).

Karate in my opinion is a "safe" choice as a testing framework, because it is technically [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin) and "language neutral". This may be a surprise for those new to Karate, but it actually leans towards using JavaScript for scripting instead of Java.

Of course, it is worth mentioning that I have yet to find a framework that makes [testing GraphQL as easy as how Karate does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469363/143475).

Answer (score -2):

Selenium and Rest assured integration framework is the answer to your question. I created a test automation framework to test an ionic application which is using GraphQL api along with Rest webservices. I have used Testng and cucumber in my framework to perform web app side validations and used Rest assured along with GSON to validate the GraphQL and rest services. You can easily integrate appium in your framework along with selenium and rest assured to cater the need of mobile testing.