# Selecting between karate and Rest assured

Tags: automation, graphql, karate, rest-assured

Trying to select between the Karate framework and Rest Assured for API automation which includes Rest APIs and GraphQL. Also we can enhance the framework to execute the UI automation

I have gone through the general process of finding:

Karate is designed for GraphQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469363/143475

For a comparison of Karate and REST-assured: https://github.com/intuit/karate#comparison-with-rest-assured

UI automation: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core

For UI automation, can it be done in the hybrid framework with Rest Assured.

Need to understand what will be the result in long term handling of both the frameworks

Moved the discussion to QA group unless it is ok to discuss here.
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/44538/selecting-between-karate-and-rest-assured

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic for SO.

Comment: Will try to be more specific and not go out of the topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate is designed for GraphQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469363/143475

For a comparison of Karate and REST-assured: https://github.com/intuit/karate#comparison-with-rest-assured

And it already supports UI automation: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have gone through those links (missed to add in the question). I am trying to understand what will be the result in long term handling of both the frameworks.

Comment: pretty good: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Community-News